# Use VBA to crop gray space from print screen

Tags: image, vba, excel, crop

I'm using Excel VBA and I would like to crop out a gray background and leave a white foreground. I'm using a CNC program, but imagine using Word and zooming out so all sides of the page is visible and the background is gray. How could I automatically crop out the background using VBA from a screenshot? The white space isn't always in the center and it varies in sizes. Any ideas?

Comment: You should include the relevant code and an errors you are getting as well .

Comment: I haven't started because I don't know where to begin! What objects/classes should I use?

Comment: You will need to elaborate more. You mention a screen shot. Are you saying you take a screen shot of something and then want to change the image? If so, check out a tool like Snag-it which is a fancier version of MS Paint that allows you to work with images.

Comment: This is my goal: I take a screen shot with Print Screen, and then I run the macro and it automatically crops the image and pastes it to a certain cell with a fixed width. I have it place it in a cell and have a fixed width, but I'm using Snipping Tool's rectangle select  to crop it basically. I want to not use Snipping Tool and just use a Print Screen that gets automatically cropped.